# Why is this SPARQL query not returning any results?

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

Runninng this query through the [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) gets me many results (with the `institution` column populated):

```
select ?person ?field ?institution where 

{
  ?person a dbpedia-owl:Agent .
  OPTIONAL { ?person dbpprop:workInstitution ?institution . }
  OPTIONAL { ?person dbpprop:workInstitutions ?institution .}
  ?person dbpprop:field ?field .
}
```

However, adding the line `FILTER(BOUND(?institution))` returns an empty result set:

```
select ?person ?field ?institution where 

{
  ?person a dbpedia-owl:Agent .
  OPTIONAL { ?person dbpprop:workInstitution ?institution . }
  OPTIONAL { ?person dbpprop:workInstitutions ?institution .}
  ?person dbpprop:field ?field .
  FILTER(BOUND(?institution))
}
```

Why is this?  I'd expect all of the results from the first query that have an `institution` result to show up, but nothing does instead.

Comment: I see that you've already accepted an answer, but I hope you'll take a look at a second answer that I've provided.  I think that the idea that "the variable is bound and unbound" isn't right, and that the spec says you should be getting results back.  I.e., I think it's a DBpedia/Virtuoso bug.  Additionally, you can reliably get the results that you want using a much simpler query than the one given in the accepted answer, using `union` or a property path.

Comment: By "bound and unbound" I meant to illustrate how the behaviour might have happened. By no means I meant that it is standard behaviour by the specification. I also suspected a bug but didn't have time to dig deeper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Quick answer:  this is a DBpedia/Virtuoso bug.

This situation is explicitly described in a presentation [*An Introduction to SPARQL Optionals* by Julian Dolby and Kavitha Srinivas](http://www.slideshare.net/juliandolby/optionals-25419705) on slide seven, in which they use an example with

```
optional { ?x name ?label }
optional { ?x nick ?label }
```

For individuals who have a `name` value, we'll never see any of the `nick` values because the `optional` patterns are left associative, according to [6 Including Optional Values](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#optionals) from the SPARQL specification.  The authors conclude on slide eight that:

> Multiple OPTIONAL clauses binding the same variable is rarely what you want.

You should get the results for the first `optional` part that matched.  That provides a binding for the variable, so `bound(...)` should be true.  As such, I'd say that the DBpedia behavior is a bug.

### Experiments with other implementations.

This is an interesting behavior, and we can reproduce it with simple data.  Suppose we have some data like this:

```
@prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/22478183/1281433/> .

:a :r :x ; :p 2 ; :q 3 .
:b :r :x ; :p 4 ; :q 5 .
```

Then we can use the following query and get the following results with Jena. We only get results for the property `:p` because `optional` is left associative, so the pattern on `:p` is covered first, and each resource in our data had a value for `:p`.

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/22478183/1281433/>

select ?x ?v where { 
  ?x :r :x .
  optional { ?x :p ?v }
  optional { ?x :q ?v }
}
```

```
----------
| x  | v |
==========
| :b | 4 |
| :a | 2 |
----------
```

With Jena, adding a `filter` doesn't remove any results, which I think is the correct behavior, because `?v` *is* bound.

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/22478183/1281433/>

select ?x ?v where { 
  ?x :r :x .
  optional { ?x :p ?v }
  optional { ?x :q ?v }
  filter(bound(?v))
}
```

```
----------
| x  | v |
==========
| :b | 4 |
| :a | 2 |
----------
```

### Union or Property paths to the rescue!

The slides cited above mention that you can use `union` inside of the `optional` to get the results you're looking for.  With the data I've provided, this means that you can do this:

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/22478183/1281433/>

select ?x ?v where { 
  ?x :r :x .
  optional { 
    { ?x :p ?v } union
    { ?x :q ?v }
  }
}
```

```
----------
| x  | v |
==========
| :b | 4 |
| :b | 5 |
| :a | 2 |
| :a | 3 |
----------
```

That works without a problem, but it can be made much more concise using property paths. If what you really want is to bind `?v` to the value of *either* the `:p` or `:q` property, you can use an alternation property path:

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/22478183/1281433/>

select ?x ?v where { 
  ?x :r :x .
  optional { ?x :p|:q ?v }
  filter(bound(?v))
}
```

```
----------
| x  | v |
==========
| :b | 4 |
| :b | 5 |
| :a | 2 |
| :a | 3 |
----------
```

Of course, if you're doing `filter(bound(?v))`, then the pattern `?x :p|:q ?v` really isn't optional anymore, so you should probably just move it into the main part of the query:

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/22478183/1281433/>

select ?x ?v where { 
  ?x :r :x ; :p|:q ?v 
}
```

```
----------
| x  | v |
==========
| :b | 4 |
| :b | 5 |
| :a | 2 |
| :a | 3 |
----------
```

Comment: that property path alternative was creative. +1

Comment: @Kristian with property paths and `values`, it's easy to get rid of lots of `union` use cases.  E.g., you want things that frobbed or quuexed a Foo or Bar?  `values ?type { :Foo :Bar } ?thing :frobbed|:quuxed [ a ?type ] .`  It makes many queries _much_ simpler. :)

Comment: that's pretty neat. i'm going to try to work those into my stuff

Comment: @Kristian Yeah, I actually kind of wish now that there were a simpler alternation syntax for objects and subjects, too.  After all, it's easy to go from `values ?type { :Foo :Bar } values ?p { :frobbed :quuxed } ?thing ?p [ a ?type ]` to what I wrote in the previous comment.  Why can't we have `?thing :frobbed|:quuxed [ a :Foo|:Bar ]`, too?

Comment: I like it. You ought to propose that in the sparql 1.x+ specification. someone may like your idea. http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/sparql#w3c_all

Answer (score -1):

The culprit is the double `OPTIONAL` on the same variable (`?institution`). What probably happens is that exactly one OPTIONAL always succeeds, that means that the other one always fails - so the `?institution` variable is always bound and not bound :)

You can work around it for example by the following query:

```
select ?person ?field ?institution

{
  ?person a dbpedia-owl:Agent .
  OPTIONAL { ?person dbpprop:workInstitution ?inst . }.
  OPTIONAL { ?person dbpprop:workInstitutions ?insts . }.
  BIND (IF(bound(?inst), ?inst, ?insts) AS ?institution )
  ?person dbpprop:field ?field .
  filter(bound(?institution)).
}
```

It checks which case succeeds and binds it to the resulting variable `?institution`.

Comment: Could this also be solved by using a single `optional` but with a alternation property path: `optional { ?person dbpprop:workInstitution|dbpprop:workInstitutions ?institution }`?

Comment: Good idea, it seems it can be solved like that too, I tried the query now and it also returns `12161` results.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the case should be fixed. The compiled SQL contains two checks, one for ?institution that comes from first OPTIONAL and one for ?institution that comes from second OPTIONAL. The formally proper compilation should be either a nested subquery with a filter on its output or FITLER (bound (?institution_1) || bound (?institution_2)) . The really proper compiler should report a warning about weird query, but warnings are not supported by SPARQL protocol :|