# how to write (union inside optional clause) or (optionals with union clause )?

Tags: union, sparql, dbpedia

for example to illustrate the issue, I need to query for some companies in sparql in dbpedia, and get their homepages.

some of these companies have a website, while others does have, so we must query inside sparql optional clause right?

so to get addresses in my query I wrote it inside optional clause as following:

```
...
optional {?company foaf:homepage ?website}
```

however not all triples stores the website address by using foaf:homepage URI, some of these triples used dbp:homepage and the previous clause will be as following:

```
...
optional {?company dbp:homepage ?website}
```

the problem is how to use UNION to get complementary data between these two clauses?

the same problem appears when querying for people data in dbpedia, for example to query for birth date :

- not all persons have birthdate literal values in dpbedia.
- some persons have birthdate in dbo:birthDate
- some persons have birthdate in dbp:birthDate

again we need to query in optional clause and need to complement/union the date.
to solve this the query should be like :

```
optional { {?person dbp:birthDate ?birthdate } union {?person dbo:birthDate ?birthdate} }
```

or as following:

```
where { {optional { ?person dbp:birthDate ?birthdate }} union {optional {?person dbo:birthDate ?birthdate}}}
```

I think I'm close, however I did not success... till now ;)

so how to solve this issue please ?

Comment: Have you considered OPTIONAL { ?company (foaf:homepage | dbp:homepage) ?website}

Comment: The question would be whether only one value should be shown by some preference on the property. This would need some IF...ELSE pattern and/or COALESCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case like this:

```
optional {?company foaf:homepage ?website}
optional {?company dbp:homepage ?website}
```

You can use an alternation property path:

```
optional {?company foaf:homepage|dbp:homepage ?website}
```

Have a look [Why is this SPARQL query not returning any results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478183/why-is-this-sparql-query-not-returning-any-results) for some discussion of one of the difficulties that can arise with having multiple **optional** blocks that bind the same variable, as well as a similar solution.